# Can't acces textblock name thats inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to obtain the value that is returned by "condition" so the idee is to use the textblocks name in an if statement so I can change the source of an image.

when I try to do it with an textblock thats outside of the datatemplate all goes wel..
but as soon as I choose an textblock thats inside the datatemplate I get an error saying that the textblock doesnt exist. I need to do it cause when the weather changes I need another image to go with it.

xaml:

```
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="99" >
                                    <Grid Height="100">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                                            
                                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=condition}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,75,10,0" Name="hulpBlock"></TextBlock>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

xaml.cs:

```
    if (hulpBlock.Text == "Partly Cloudy")
         { weatherframe.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("WeatherIcons/03.png"); }
```

Comment: Here's a challenge--[edit] your question and fix your code/xaml formatting.  Getting that right will ensure you get good answers in future.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your weatherframe.Source to be updated, you would have to subscribe to the changed event on the Text Property of your TextBlock.  A more elegant way to do it is to implement `weatherframe.Source` as a Dependency Property if it isn't already, then you can just bind `condition` to `weatherframe.Source` with the appropriate `Value Converter` directly.

Your `ValueConverter` should look something similar to this:

```
public class StringToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || !(value is string))
        {
            return null; //Handle error your way here
        }
        if ((string)value == "Partly Cloudy")
        {
            return new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("WeatherIcons/03.png");
        }
        else
        {
           // More Implementations and error handling etc
        }
        return null;
    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then in your XAML:

In your resources section:

```
<StringToImageConverter x:Key="StringToImageConverter"/>
```

In your GUI:

```
 <Weatherframe Source="{Binding Path=condition, Converter={StaticResource StringToImageConverter}}" Name="weatherframe"></Weatherframe>
```

Comment: Thanx for your help.. but I dont understand.. could you make me an example.. I'm still a beginner..

Comment: Thanx again for your reply.. but i ran into a few other isuess

Comment: Looks like i implemented the xaml.cs code fine (no error just had to ad a few resources) But I dont know where in the xaml I should implement those two xaml lines..

Comment: You need to set up the Source property on your Weatherframe object to accept the condition as a binding source, and then use the StringToImageConverter to convert the condition string to the image you want.  I cannot do this for you since I can't see your code.  Read more about how databinding works online, if you are gonna be programming in WPF/Silverlight you absolutely have to master its databinding features.

Comment: I'v changed the source of the Weatherframe to the following: <Image Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="Weatherframe" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Source="{Binding Path=condition, Converter=StaticResource StringToImageConverter}}" /> So that shouldnt be a problem anymore..

Comment: but for the next:<StringToImageConverter x:Key="StringToImageConverter"/> I've placed it on the App.Xaml page between the: <Application.Resources></Application.Resources> And get the following error:Error 1 The type 'StringToImageConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. I'm not sure but got the feeling that I'm close or completly on the wrong track..

Comment: You need to append the namespace for StringToImageConverter in your resource declaration like this <YourNameSpace:StringToImageConverter x:Key="StringToImageConverter"/>  Substitute YourNameSpace for the name space you declared for StringToImageConverter in your cs file.

Comment: I've edited my question. maybe its a little bit more clear what I'm trieng to accomplish. :-S

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved:

I gave the textblock an "loaded event handeler"

```
    <TextBlock Loaded="test_Loaded" Text="{Binding Path=condition}"  Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,75,10,0" x:Name="temp" ></TextBlock>
```

And did this in my xaml.cs:

```
    private void test_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var hulpBlock = sender as TextBlock;
        if (hulpBlock.Text.Trim().Equals("Partly Cloudy"))
        {
            Weatherframe.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("WeatherIcons/03.png");
        }
    }
```

my data get pulled in from an internet xml source. and suposibly there is some extra hidden data in the text which
makes it impossible for the hulpBlock.Text to equal  "Partly Cloudy" but the trimmer did the job .. :-)